# How to make external lib work in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I've been trying hard to make all my external libs as such in my webpack project. Everything seemed to worked until today, now everything crashes again and i don't get why. It's probably due to my config that was luckily working before in a previous version of webpack or something. Does someone know how to properly configure externals? Following webpack doc step by step leads to no result. Here is my relevant code :

#### webpack.config.js

```
externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    d3: 'd3',
    lodash : '_',
    moment: 'moment',
    backbone: 'Backbone',
    "pdfjs-dist": "window.pdfjsLib"
}
```

I also have a plugin about jquery

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery'
    })
]
```

#### index.html

```
<script src="./vendor/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/d3.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/moment.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/pdf/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app-asd98u9a8d.js"></script>
```

Here is a sample of my main script. It crashes at the `$(document)` line

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
}
```

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

It's very important to notice that $ is defined... but it's not the proper object. If i want the proper object at this point, it should be `$.default`. So it's like if the import doesn't give me the right object.

What did i miss?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem seems to be around the import `import * as $ from 'jquery;'` instead of `import $ from 'jquery';`. The problem is that typescript says that there is no default export in jquery lib based on the d.ts file that goes with the lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i managed to make it work. By looking at the generated code, i found that the function called in case of `import * as $ from 'jquery'` returns as expected a global variable that does not contain the default export even if it exists. Replacing all the calls by `let $ = require('jquery')` fixed it as it now looks for the default export.